# UITableViewCell (MTD) rectangle style cell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Hi I have my Monotouch application and I would like to implement using Monotouch Dialog a cell with the following style (rectangle and spacing between cells)

Here is a sample image:

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a custom cell renderer.

MonoTouch.Dialog has several examples showing how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, is it possible in this custom cell renderer to have an editor? Thanks

Comment: MT D is a code only toolkit (which is one of its strengths IMO). So no editor